# Time taken for loop vs map flatmap combination

Tags: scala

Iam trying to understand functional programming using scala. So the question is very basic. To start off, I have a trait which looks something like this

```scala
trait DebugLogger{
  def time(stageName:String)(func : => Unit):Unit = {
    val currentTime= System.currentTimeMillis()
    println(s"Stage ${stageName} started at ${currentTime}")
    func
    println(s"Stage ${stageName} completed.. Took ${(System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime)/1000.0} seconds")
  }
}
```

Now I have a function which looks something like this

```scala
object GeneralRecap extends App with DebugLogger {
  val aCondition: Boolean = true
  val list1 = Seq(1,2,4,4)
  val list2 = Seq('a','b','c','d')
  time ("Time taken in for loop"){
    val a1 = for (i <- list1;
                  j <- list2
                  ) yield i * j
    println(a1)
  }

time("Time taken in flatmap") {
  val c = list1 flatMap (number => list2.map(value => number * value))
  println(c)
}
```

I was assuming the bytecode that both the functions would generate would be the same and was assuming both the functions would take the same time to process. However to my surprise this is how the output ended up with

```
Stage Time taken in for loop started at 1661398450618
List(97, 98, 99, 100, 194, 196, 198, 200, 388, 392, 396, 400, 388, 392, 396, 400)
Stage Time taken in for loop completed.. Took 0.011 seconds
Stage Time taken in flatmap started at 1661398450629
List(97, 98, 99, 100, 194, 196, 198, 200, 388, 392, 396, 400, 388, 392, 396, 400)
Stage Time taken in flatmap completed.. Took 0.001 seconds
```

So the flatmap map way takes 1/10th of the for loop time. Considering both the functions are n square, I would assume that it should have taken the same time. Any reason why the first one takes more time than the other

Comment: Probably because you are not benchmarking correctly in the slightest way at all.

Comment: What do you expect to see? I'm getting 0.0 seconds on both your examples.  You can play with bigger Ranges but their time should be roughly the same. For-comprehensions get translated into a sequence of flatmaps ending with a map.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip: For me one took 0.011 s vs 0.001 s no matter how many times i run the result is the same.

Comment: I generally recommend that anyone wanting to benchmark code on any modern high-performance language implementation read and fully understand https://groups.google.com/g/mechanical-sympathy/c/m4opvy4xq3U/m/7lY8x8SvHgwJ before doing so. Benchmarking is hard. Really hard. Usually, the people writing benchmarks are doing that exclusively, full-time, professionally, 8 hours a day, 5 days a week for many years. And even they still get it wrong. (There is a famous example from the SPEC suite which was supposed to test DB perf and ended up testing memory allocation.)

Comment: Unless you have a deep and firm grasp of computer architecture, CPU architecture and microarchitecture, RAM, compilers, interpreters, garbage collectors, memory allocators, operating systems, kernels, schedulers, etc., you have basically no chance of writing a useful benchmark. *And* you also need advanced understanding of statistics in order to correctly interpret the results. In fact, I consider myself knowledgeable in all of these things, but I still don't consider myself capable of writing and/or interpreting a benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are all sorts of problems with that `time` method. Firstly it is including the time for the first `println` in the total, and secondly there may well be formatting code executed before the second time is captured.

This is a much better version:

```
def time(stageName: String)(func: => Unit): Unit = {
  println(s"Starting ${stageName}")

  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  func
  val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

  val elapsed = (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0

  println(s"Stage ${stageName} completed. Took $elapsed seconds")
}
```

More importantly you can't measure Scala performance on a single run. There is a lot of optimisation that happens during the run of a program that means that the first pass is usually significantly slower than the later ones.

Comment: I generally recommend that anyone wanting to benchmark code on any modern high-performance language implementation read and fully understand https://groups.google.com/g/mechanical-sympathy/c/m4opvy4xq3U/m/7lY8x8SvHgwJ before doing so. Benchmarking is hard. Really hard. Usually, the people writing benchmarks are doing that exclusively, full-time, professionally, 8 hours a day, 5 days a week for many years. And even they still get it wrong. (There is a famous example from the SPEC suite which was supposed to test DB perf and ended up testing memory allocation.)